# Is public IP unique?

Tags: router, ip

is public IP unique?
I mean that we have two kind of IP: private and public
and if public IP belongs to router,does every one connect to one router have a single IP address or not?

Comment: On the internet, every IP address is unique.

Comment: so whats difference between  public and private IP? and what is public IP?

Comment: Please [edit] your question if it didn't cover what you wanted to know, rather than using comments to discuss.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general terms the answer is yes, public IPs are globally unique.

**In the IPv4 context**, the IPs (v4) known for not being unique are the private IPs, these are found in the following ranges:

- From 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255.
- From 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255.
- From 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255.

see  [rfc1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html/)

The IP your home router has on the "internet side" interface is public, given by your ISP. The IPs you use in your home's WiFi side or Ethernet Lan connection those are private, so they are not unique but it's not a problem because those never leave your home before being NATed or translated by the NAT.

**EDIT:**

Now, as mentioned on the comments below, there is an exception to what I just said. There are some techniques that allow us to be more flexible about the one-to-one communication original internet protocol paradigm to allow one-to-nearest. These techniques are used for example when talking about services that need high availability, redundancy or low latency like DNS, or CDN services. Given a certain IP (IPv4 or IPv6),there might be more that one server in the world configured to answer to that IP, nevertheless only one will be answering.

see [rfc4786](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4786)

Moreover, IPv6 introduced a new addressing system that copes with these "new needs", and it defined the "Anycast Address"

> 

IP Version 6 (IPv6) defines a new type of address, known as an
"anycast" address, that allows a packet to be routed to one of a
number of different nodes all responding to the same address [2, 3].
The anycast address may be assigned to one or more network interfaces
(typically on different nodes), with the network delivering each
packet addressed to this address to the "nearest" interface based on
the notion of "distance" determined by the routing protocols in use.

see [rfc2526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2526)

**About IPv6 Anycast Address**

> An anycast address is an address that is assigned to a set of
> interfaces that typically belong to different nodes. A packet sent to
> an anycast address is delivered to the closest interface (as defined
> by the routing protocols in use) identified by the anycast address.
> Anycast addresses are syntactically indistinguishable from unicast
> addresses, because anycast addresses are allocated from the unicast
> address space. Assigning a unicast address to more than one interface
> makes a unicast address an anycast address. Nodes to which the anycast
> address is assigned must be explicitly configured to recognize that
> the address is an anycast address.

see [cisco source](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/configuration/15-2mt/ip6-15-2mt-book/ip6-anycast-add.html#GUID-47959F37-6890-463C-8547-EF992FDE9594)

Comment: You could say that private IPs are unique as well. They cannot be accessed from outside the network, and within that local network they are unique. So no matter where you are, the private IP is unique as well for your setup.

Comment: The actual public IP may be a NAT though, where many customers share the same public IP. This is sometimes the case with IPs that don't allocate static IPs to individual customers without paying extra.

Comment: Nitpick. The three RFC1918 ranges which you specified and 127/8.

Comment: Nitpick 2: and 169.254.0.0/16, per RFC 3927. (Link-local IP)

Comment: I suspect there are several machines with the address `8.8.8.8` (Google Public DNS). I would expect it to be hosted in the USA, but I'm in Switzerland and a ping to that address yields around 17ms (in comparison, `www.whitehouse.gov` yields around 106ms). I don't know much about BGP, but would it be possible to advertise different routes for a same IP, depending of the geographic position?

Comment: @Reyssor: Yes, that is called [anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast), where more than one network has the same IP block. See Daniel B's answer

Comment: Also, this answer only gives example specific to IPv4, where IPv6 information would be beneficial too, given the rising usage of IPv6

Comment: that is very helpful...i think i understand that completely thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

No, it’s not. This is in fact quite common. The technology behind this is called [Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) and used by many content-distribution networks, like CloudFlare.

> Anycast is a network addressing and routing methodology in which datagrams from a single sender are routed to the topologically nearest node in a group of potential receivers, though it may be sent to several nodes, **all identified by the same destination address**.

Then, there’s also the possibility to (temporarily) steal others’ IP addresses. This is relatively easy if you’re an Autonomous System operator. You can simply announce that you’re hosting some IPs and traffic will magically be directed to you. Of course, the legitimate owner also broadcasts these announcements, so the effect is temporary and incomplete at best.

Only in [unicast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicast) addressing is an IP address unique.

Answer (score 4):

**Public IP** is the one you are visible with in the Internet.

**Private IP** is the one you are visible with in your private network, like behind router.

Everyone who connects to router has a single **private IP**, but in most common configuration they all share single **public IP** which, in common case, is assigned to the router, not computer.

It is possible to assign public IP for every single computer, but you have router which allows so and you must own enough of public addresses to assign. You have to buy them first.

Answer (score 0):

Your public IP is unique *by definition*. It it was not unique, it could not be a public address, as it would be impossible to determine where to route your traffic.

In other words: your public IP address is the external (Internet-facing) address of the router closest to you which is still unique world-wide. That may or may not be your own router at home, although it usually is.

As pointed out though, some ISPs use [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to conserve IPv4 addresses, in which case your home router's external address may not be a unique one and your public IP address belongs to a router further along, at your ISP (and you share it with other customers of the ISP).